# Firestore - Merging two queries locally

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Since there is no logical `OR` operator in Firestore, I am trying to merge 2 separate queries locally.

Now I wonder how I can keep up the proper order of the results. When I run 2 queries independently, I can't oder the results specificly (at least not the order in which I get the results from Firestore with the `orderBy` method).

My idea was to put the 2nd query inside the `onSuccessListener` of the 1st query. Is this a bad idea performance wise?

```
public void loadNotes(View v) {
    collectionRef.whereLessThan("priority", 2)
            .orderBy("priority")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Note note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                        //adding the results to a List
                    }

                    collectionRef.whereGreaterThan("priority", 2)
                            .orderBy("priority")
                            .get()
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                        Note note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                                        //adding the results to a List
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To merge 2 separate queries locally, I recommend you to use `Tasks.whenAllSuccess()` method. You can achieve this, using the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query firstQuery = rootRef...
Query secondQuery = rootRef...

Task firstTask = firstQuery.get();
Task secondTask = secondQuery.get();

Task combinedTask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(firstTask, secondTask).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
         //Do what you need to do with your list
    }
});
```

As you can see, when overriding the `onSuccess()` method the result is a `list` of objects which has the exact order of the tasks that were passed as arguments into the `whenAllSuccess()` method.

There is also another approach and that would be to use `Tasks.continueWith()` method. But according to the use-case of your app, you can use eiter `whenAllSuccess()` method or `continueWith()` method. Please see here the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks).

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually found the same solutions online, but I was highly insecure if they are correct, because I found so little examples. Now that you name the exact same methods, I have insurance.
One thing: I am a newbie so I have problems with generics, but I noticed that when I write `Task<List<QuerySnapshot>> combinedTask` instead of declaring the type just as `Task`, I get a `List<QuerySnapshot>` in OnSucess, instead of a `List<Object`, which makes it more convenient. Is this the correct way of declaring the type?

Comment: [QuerySnapshot](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) class, like every other class in Java extends the `Object` class. Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. So `QuerySnapshot` is-a Object. The `QuerySnapshot` a related type in ths case, so feel free to use `List<QuerySnapshot>`.

Comment: Ok, but is this better than casting the `objects` in `onSuccess` or does it not matter?

Comment: Is no difference at all. Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916538/casting-and-generics-any-performance-difference).

Comment: I just try to understand why it returns that as a List of Objects in the first place. Is it because I can pass different kind of Tasks to whenAllSuccess?

Comment: It returns a List of Objects because you are not indicating a proper class at all. So the generic class for the list, is set to the root class of all objects. Every class in Java "is-a" Object. When you are using generics you are indicating the exact type of the containing objects so the list will contain objects of type `QuerySnapshot` and not Object. Right?

Comment: Right, but the `get` method on a `CollectionReference` returns a `Task<QuerySnapshot` without me defining anything. That's why I wonder why there is more freedom in the `whenAllSucess` method.

As a beginner I just wonder if the reason "I don't want to cast the objects" is reasonable to save it in a variable with a generic type.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is happening because the [onComplete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/OnCompleteListener) is defined as `onComplete(Task<T> task)` and when is called on a `CollectionReference` it will only return `Task<QuerySnapshot>` but when called on `Tasks.whenAllSuccess(firstTask, secondTask)` can return a List of different types of objects. Android Studio doesn't know what kind of objects might be and that's why it returns a generic list of objects, right?

Comment: Right, I understand why Android Studio sets the type like this. As a beginner it's sometimes just hard to figure out best practices, and I wonder if defining the generic type just for the sake of code readability (like I do in my approach) is reasonable. But from what I read about generic types, one benefit is to avoid casting, so it seems reasonable.

Comment: Yes it is. You can go ahead in this way. Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes, it solved the question and was very helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @AlexMamo Hi, Can I do pagination here? limit 10 on both queries? and get 20 results in combined task?

Comment: @SurabhiChoudhary You can check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50281966/firebase-firestore-subcollection-of-documents-from-document)** and **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50592325/is-there-a-way-to-paginate-queries-by-combining-query-cursors-using-firestorerec/50692959)** out.

Comment: In cases like this, how are read charges calculated? Is it for both the result set or for combined one? Like in first filter we get 20 results and in second after more filtering we get 10, so we will be charged for 10, 20 or 30?

Comment: @SurabhiChoudhary You will be charged with the combined number of elements that are returned by the queries.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMamo for replying so fast. Really obliged. Last question, can this be used with snapshot listeners?

Comment: @SurabhiChoudhary No, only when you use a `get()` call, since `get()` returns a `Task` object.

Comment: @SurabhiChoudhary how did you cast it to a QuerySnapshot, could you post an example please.

Comment: @SabeehUlHaq I'm not sure I understand the question. If you have a hard time implementing that, post a new question and show us what you have tried. In this way, I or other developers will be able help you.

Comment: @AlexMamo so the answer on Feb 27 '20 would be 10 or 30?

Comment: @fkvestak 10 or 30 what?

Comment: @AlexMamo someone asked will we be charged for 10, 20 or 30 results in his example?
Let's say my first query returns 200 results, second one returns 50, third one returns 10. I will render these 10 items because they satisfy all 3 queries. But, how much will I be charged? 10 document reads, or 260?

Comment: @fkvestak You'll **always** be charged with a number of read operations that is equal to the number of elements that are returned. If you have, for example, three queries, and each one of them returns three documents, you'll be charged with 9 document reads.

Comment: @AlexMamo that's what I was afraid about. That is really bad, which makes Firestore basically useless, even for a basic TODO app.

Comment: @fkvestak I think this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) will provide even more info. It really isn't what you say.

Comment: @AlexMamo your article looks really nice, I will get into it this evening ;)

Comment: @fkvestak Good to hear that ;)

Comment: @AlexMamo Do you have informations/experience about running 2 queries? Everyones always saying best practise is running 1 query & duplicate data instead. Me for example im building a dating app & i want to show clients profile recommendations. I need to make sure they didnt see the profile yet or liked it. Im saving the user likes in an own collection. Therefor I would get 5 profiles, take the ids and check if they are in the users collection (10reads). Makes more sense for me than saving all the data again somewhereelse on the user, I still wouldnt be able to get my results. what do you think

Comment: @MarcelDz Might work for sure your scenario, but if have something special, other than running multiple queries (which is quite normal), please post a new question here on Stackoverflow using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: @AlexMamo alright I did so, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66884058/firebase-firestore-flutter-run-multiple-queries-vs-denormalize-data waiting eagerly for your input. Greetings Marcel