# Firestore merge 2 Queries and Query with OR

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to Query Objects from a Collection where "equipmentOption" == equipmentOption || "equipmentOption" == -1.

After researching this problem I came to the conclusion that this is not possible with Firestore Querys. Is that correct or is there a way to query like this?

So my Solution was to have two separate Queries like this:

```
Task<QuerySnapshot> routinesWithEquipmentOption = doc.getReference().collection("Routines").whereEqualTo("equipmentOption", programm.getEquipmentOption()).get();
Task<QuerySnapshot> routinesWithoutEquipmentOption = doc.getReference().collection("Routines").whereEqualTo("equipmentOption", -1).get();
```

and the somehow merge this query. Thats what I accomplished:

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess(routinesWithEquipmentOption, routinesWithoutEquipmentOption).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Object> objects) {

                    }
                });
```

In this OnSuccessListner I get a List of Objects. This confuses me, what information do these Objects contain. Is there a way to convert them to a DocumentSnapshot so I can call `.toObject()`? Also it seems like I don't get anything back because onSuccess is never called.

Comment: If onSuccess is not being called, maybe there is an error in either one of the queries.  What happens if you check their results individually?

Comment: Are those tasks/queries even correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore - Merging two queries locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally)