# Firebase Firestore subcollection of documents from document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my collection's SnapshotListener, I have am looping through the documents with:

```
for (DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
    if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
        String somestr = doc.getDocument.getString("someField");
        // retrieve collection here
    }
}
```

And within each document in the for loop, let's call it `doc`, I have another collection of documents on Cloud Firestore.  I would like to retrieve all documents (each of which just has a single String field) within the subcollection inside `doc`.  I'm able to do a `doc.getDocument` to get `doc` itself, which I am using to get a string field, but I don't know how to get the documents in its subcollection.

Answer (score 1):

You first get the subcollection with:

```
doc.getDocument().getReference().getCollection("subcollection")
```

And then you get the documents in there like you did before (or as shown in [this documentation section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection)).