# Firebase query to fetch data in given range

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node called **quotes** in Firebase. I'm facing issues while fetching data in Android for a particular range. I want to fetch 3 continues quotes id starting from 2. Here is my query database:

```
"quotes" : {
"-L75elQJaD3EYPsd4oWS" : {
  "authorName" : "Hellen v",
  "famousQuote" : "When one door of happiness closes, another opens; but often we look so long at the closed door that we do not see the one which has been opened for us.",
  "id" : "1",
  "uploadedBy" : "Admin"
},
"-L7GOvDNI-o_H8RvNwoN" : {
  "authorName" : "Rocky Balboa",
  "famousQuote" : "It's not about how hard you can hit; it's about how hard you can get hit and keep moving forward.",
  "id" : "2",
  "uploadedBy" : "Admin"
},
"-L7GP9oBv5NR1T6HlDd4" : {
  "authorName" : "African proverb",
  "famousQuote" : "If you want to go fast, go alone. If you want to go far, go together.",
  "id" : "3",
  "uploadedBy" : "Admin"
},
"-L7GPjM1F3_7Orcz0Q1q" : {
  "authorName" : "A.P.J Abdul Kalam",
  "famousQuote" : "Don’t take rest after your first victory because if you fail in second, more lips are waiting to say that your first victory was just luck.",
  "id" : "4",
  "uploadedBy" : "Admin"
},
```

**Below is the rule which I'm using for quotes**

```
"quotes": {
 ".indexOn": ".value"
}
```

**How can I get quotes which has id 2,3 and 4?**

Comment: Can you explain what have you tried and what went wrong? What issues are you facing?

Comment: I've tried below queries 
**1**. `Query quotes = mFirebaseDatabase.child("quotes").orderByValue
                .startAt(2);` - Here I am getting all nodes which is present inside quotes.
**2** `Query quotes = mFirebaseDatabase.child("quotes").orderByValue
                .startAt(2).limitToFirst(3);` - Here I am getting top 3 results.

Comment: And what went wrong? did you get it until 4? Or no?

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 4 records in your database, to solve this, you can use a query in which you should combine `startAt()` and `endAt()` methods to limit both ends of your query like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("quotes").orderByChild("id").startAt("2").endAt("4");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Please see here more informations about Firebase Query's [startAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#startAt(double)) method:

> Create a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value greater than or equal to the given value, using the given orderBy directive or priority as default.

And here are more informations about Firebase Query's [endAt()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#endAt(double)) method:

> Create a query constrained to only return child nodes with a value less than or equal to the given value, using the given orderBy directive or priority as default.

**Edit:** According to your comment, if you only want the items that have the `id` property set to 2, 3 and 4, you should use nested queries like this:

```
Query queryTwo = rootRef.child("quotes").orderByChild("id").equalsTo("2");
queryTwo.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
    List<Item> list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(itemTwo);
    Query queryThree = rootRef.child("quotes").orderByChild("id").equalsTo("3");
    queryThree.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
        list.add(itemThree);
        Query queryFour = rootRef.child("quotes").orderByChild("id").equalsTo("4");
        queryFour.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            list.add(itemFour);

            //Do what you need to do with the list that contains three items
        );
    );
);
```

Comment: The `id` values are stored as strings, so `.startAt("2").endAt("4")`.

Comment: @Alex, I have more than 500 records in my database. When I'm using `Query query = rootRef.child("quotes").orderByChild("id").startAt("2").endAt("4");` I am getting the records which has the id as 2,3 and 4 but along with also getting the records which has id as 21,22,40,42.. etc. I need only 2,3 and 4.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh my bad, you're right Puf, just updated my answer. If you see in the future any other inconsistency in my code, please feel free to correct it. Thanks!

Comment: If you consider moving to Cloud Firestore, you can achieve this in a more simpler way, as explained in my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally/50132229)**.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?