# Way to store Tags for good Query options?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Collection of Posts and a Collection of Users. Posts have certain attributes which are irrelevant for this, but they also have one attribute called `tags` right now its an array with certain words.

A User can follow certain Tags so he has a attribute `followedTags` which is also an Array right now that contains the Tags he follows.

Now one of the use cases for this is a User Feed to Show only Posts with Tags he follows, the Problem is that I only found methods to query this for ONE Attribute at a time(in Arrays). Since I dont wanna run 20 Querys for 1 Feed (For example if the user follows 20 Tags) I thought maybe I could make a smart change in the data modell itself, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> Problem is that I only found methods to query this for ONE Attribute at a time(in Arrays)

If you try to chain multiple `whereArrayContains()` methods, you're most likely getting the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Query. Queries only support having a single array-contains filter.

So unfortunately Firestore can **only** allow a single call to `whereArrayContains()` method in query.

> Since I dont wanna run 20 Querys for 1 Feed (For example if the user follows 20 Tags)

If you have a reasonable number tags, you can create each tag as a separate property. In this case, it is allowed to call Firestore Query's [whereEqualTo()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query.html#whereEqualTo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) multiple times.

If this is not the case, then you should consider augmenting your database structure to allow a reverse lookup by creating each tag as a seprate object (document) in a `tagCollection`. Under each document you can create a new collection named `tagPost` in which you should add all the posts that are labeled with a specific tag.

Comment: Even if I would use your solution on the bottom, how would I query only for Posts that contain those 2 Tags? It gets really messy then and I would prefer a simpler solution

Comment: Using my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally/50132229)**. If it is for Android, you create two separate task objects and then pass them to the `whenAllSuccess()` method :) If it is for other programming language, you should check the docs.

Comment: Does something like that exist in JS?

Comment: Do you think that my answer/comment helped you regarding the initial question?

Comment: I didn´t find something equal to it, yes your answer helps me but doesnt fully solve my question, take my upvote but with best answer I´ll wait for more.

Comment: You questions were: `Way to store Tags for good Query options?` which is answered + those 2 that are also answered. Mostly, we stick to 1 question of a time. If you have another problem, post a new question for that problem with its own MCVE. The fact that you have another question sounds as a new issue which basically should be considered another question that cannot be answered in a comment or using only the data above. So in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so me and other users can help you.

Comment: I asked for Data Modell Suggestions based on the Structure I provided above because my current Data Modell isnt optimal for my use case

Comment: So this what I was talking about. I have provided you two ways in which you can store the tags. Now according to your use case, you can choose to use either the first one or the second one. So you should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else like (how to display the data from tho collections) comes up.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Im thinking about adding the Tags as a Property of the Document instead but im not sure on how to name it, how to Query it properly etc., still trying to figure out the best way that allows me to make a Feed of Posts that contain a list of tags, a Post will only have like 2-3 Tags max.

Comment: If it will have only 2-3 tags, then you definitely should add them as properties and chain `whereEqualTo()` method. The properties might look like this: `tag1: true`, `tag2:true` and so on.

Comment: If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. I'd appreciate it. Thanks!