# Returning an object returned by an asynchronous method

Tags: java, android, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

In the context of an Android development using Cloud Firestore database, I am writing the method `get(int id) : MyDO` of my DAO class. Since, in Firestore, all the operations are asynchronous, the use of the return, a `MyDO` object, must take account of this asynchronous aspect.

A first solution would be the callback. The method `get` I'm writting could accepts a callback parameter (as a second parameter) in which I would put the code, in the call to `get`, that uses the object `MyDO`. However, I don't want it.

I know a bit about promises, or even `await/async`. Would these notions be useful in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no promises in Java nor await/async, only in Javascript you can find that. More informations [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions#simplify_asynchronous_code_with_javascript_promises).

In Android, instead of returning a `Promise` it retruns a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task).

So if you don't want to use a [custom callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/firestore-object-with-inner-object/48500679), you might consider using the following solution:

- [Firestore - Merging two queries locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally/)