# Is it possible to access a sub collections from parent collections (firebase cloud firestore)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection like bellow:

```
db.collection("col1/doc1/col2/doc2/col3/doc3/col4").get();
```

Now I have to get all collection **collection2** and **collection4**

With my current know knowledge I have to get them separately like bellow:

```
db.collection("col1/doc1/col2").get();
```

and

```
db.collection("col1/doc1/col2/doc2/col3/doc3/col4").get();
```

*My expectation is I want to call it at once with* **collection2**

```
db.collection("col1/doc1/col2").get().then(snapshot=>{
   //here something like snapshot.col3.col4
});
```

Is it possible like `snapshot.col3.col4`?

**Why I want like this ?**

*Because I will not have to call it more than one time from server, may it increase performance and make it faster.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible like snapshot.col3.col4?

No, it's not. Queries in Firestore are shallow, which means that only get items from a collection that the query is run against. There is no way you can get documents from a top-level collection and a subcollections with different names in the same time. Firestore doesn't support queries across different collections with different names in one go. A single query may only use properties of documents in a single collection.

A possible solution for your issue might be the use of [Collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), but as the doc states, all collections should have the same name.

Another workaround might be, to create two separate queries and merge the result client side. For that I recommend you see my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore - Merging two queries locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally/50132229)