# How to know when multi SnapshotListener finish?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I know where many `SnapshotListener` of a different collections has been completed?

Take an example of trying to retrieve a user from a user collection, a team from the teams collection, and a coach from the coaches collection.

I want to make the activity "active" only when i got all the data that I am looking for.

For example:

```
  firebaseFirestore.collectionGroup("users").whereEqualTo("user_id", currentUser.getId()).addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                   // getting the user
                    }

  firebaseFirestore.collectionGroup("teams").whereEqualTo("team_id", currentTeam.getId()).addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                   // getting the team
                    }


  firebaseFirestore.collectionGroup("coachs").whereEqualTo("coach_id", currentCoach.getId()).addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                   // getting the coach
                    }
```

How do I make sure that only when I got all the three i will make my activity "enable"?

Comment: I could make a three booleans in my viewmodel that represnts if the data is ready for each snapshot, and on each complete listiner update the value and call to a synchronized method that looks for the three booleans and if there are all true, update the activity. But is there more "elegant" way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know when getting the data from the database using `addSnapshotListener()` has completed becase Cloud Firestore is a realtime database and getting data might never complete. That's why is named a realtime database because in any momemnt the database can be changed, items can be added or deleted.

The only way to partially know if you have all the data from a particular query is to perform a `get()` call on that query. Even then, the data may change after that listener is invoked, so all you really have is a `snapshot` at a particular moment in time.

In your particular case, you can use `get()` in case of each query and save that in a Task object. To know when all tasks are complete, please use my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore - Merging two queries locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally/50132229)

But instead of using two queries, you should use three.

You can use a `CompletionListener` only when you **write** or **update** data in your database and you'll be notified when the operation has been acknowledged by the Firebase servers but you cannot use this interface when reading data.