# How to merge two queries using Firestore - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to merge two queries with firebase firestore and then order the results using the `timestamp` field of the documents.
Online I didn't find much information regarding Swift and Firestore.
This is what I did so far:

```
db.collection("Notes").whereField("fromUid", isEqualTo: currentUserUid as Any).whereField("toUid", isEqualTo: chatUserUid as Any).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        db.collection("Notes").whereField("fromUid", isEqualTo: self.chatUserUid as Any).whereField("toUid", isEqualTo: self.currentUserUid as Any).getDocuments { (snaphot1, error1) in
            if let err = error1{
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

I added the second query inside the first one `on completion` but now I don't know how to merge them and order them through the field of `timestamp`.

On this insightful [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally) It is explained that it's recommended to use a Task object but I don't find anything similar with swift.

Comment: There is probably no need to merge the data but the question is pretty unclear - the nested query doesn't appear to have any relation to the top level one other than it will occur after the first query has returned data in it's snapshot. However, you're not doing anything with that data. Can you please include your Firestore structure and clarify what the queries are supposed to be doing and what the end result is supposed to be

Comment: I need to get all documents which corresponds to the respective "fromUid" and "toUid", then also all the document that corresponds to the reverse of the uids. 
After doing that I would group all the data retrieved and order them by timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this; here's one option.

To provide an answer, we have to make a couple of additions; first, we need somewhere to store the data retrieved from firebase so here's a class to contains some chat information

```
class ChatClass {
    var from = ""
    var to = ""
    var msg = ""
    var timestamp = 0

    convenience init(withDoc: DocumentSnapshot) {
        self.init()
        self.from = withDoc.get("from") as! String
        self.to = withDoc.get("to") as! String
        self.msg = withDoc.get("msg") as! String
        self.timestamp = withDoc.get("timestamp") as! Int
    }
}
```

then we need a class level array to store it so we can use it later - perhaps as a tableView dataSource

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var sortedChatArray = [ChatClass]()
```

The setup is we have two users, Jay and Cindy and we want to retrieve all of the chats between them and sort by timestamp (just an Int in this case).

Here's the code that reads in all of the chats from one user to another creates ChatClass objects and adds them to an array. When complete that array is passed back to the calling completion handler for further processing.

```
func chatQuery(from: String, to: String, completion: @escaping( [ChatClass] ) -> Void) {
    let chatsColl = self.db.collection("chats") //self.db points to my Firestore
    chatsColl.whereField("from", isEqualTo: from).whereField("to", isEqualTo: to).getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let docs = snapshot?.documents else { return }

        var chatArray = [ChatClass]()

        for doc in docs {
            let chat = ChatClass(withDoc: doc)
            chatArray.append(chat)
        }

        completion(chatArray)
    })
}
```

Then the tricky bit. The code calls the above code which returns an array The above code is called again, returning another array. The arrays are combined, sorted and printed to console.

```
func buildChatArray() {
    self.chatQuery(from: "Jay", to: "Cindy", completion: { jayCindyArray in
        self.chatQuery(from: "Cindy", to: "Jay", completion: { cindyJayArray in
            let unsortedArray = jayCindyArray + cindyJayArray
            self.sortedChatArray = unsortedArray.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp < $1.timestamp })

            for chat in self.sortedChatArray {
                print(chat.timestamp, chat.from, chat.to, chat.msg)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

and the output

```
ts: 2  from: Cindy  to: Jay  msg: Hey Jay, Sup.
ts: 3  from: Jay    to: Cindy  msg: Hi Cindy. Not much
ts: 9  from: Jay    to: Cindy  msg: Talk to you later
```

Comment: really complete answer, upvoted, The model and storage part weren't included because I wanted to keep the question as simple as possible, but anyway thank you for your clarification!