# How to combine two queries FirebaseDatabase?

Tags: android, firebase

Is there any way to combine two queries and make it one?

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rooms");
        Query query = ref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);
        Query query1 = ref.orderByChild("cate").equalTo("private");
        query.orderByChild(query1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

Comment: As far as I know Firebase Realtime database does not support multiple queries, you can use FireStore.

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally/50132229)** is how you can combine two queries.