# Firebase Firestore Flutter run multiple queries vs. denormalize data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a dating app and I'm trying to find the best approach showing clients recommendations for other user profiles on my home screen based on their behavior.

So in my case they have to match certain criterias (gender, age) and I have to make sure that the client didn't like them yet. Matching criterias works fine, but filtering out all the profiles which where already liked seems to be quite hard.

I've already learned that denormalizing data is a good approach keeping queries simple. But for my case it doesn't make sense to me. I don't see a way accomplishinging this without duplicating millions of data.

This is my firestore structure:

```
users       - documentId 
                 - userName
                 - firstName
                 - lastName
                 - city
profiles    - documentId 
                - userId
                - firstName
                - lastName
                - city
                - gender
            - subcollection likes 
            - documentId 
                - userId
                - timestamp
```

This is how I get profiles (minified example):

```
CollectionReference profileRef = _db.collection('profiles');

    // Query definition
    final ref = profileRef
    .where('criteria', arrayContainsAny: criteria)
    .limit(5);
```

**Thinking of a solution**
I thought about getting the profiles first like in the above query, save the Ids to a list and run a second query by finding out if the user already liked the profile. It would cost me 10 reads and the fact not having all the data from a single query.

I already read in the docs and watched firebase youtube channel, but I didn't find any benchmarks/experience/advices on running multiple queries or furthermore when to do what in the special use case.

I would love to have some input from you guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think another possible solution could be by changing a bit the Firestore structure.

For example you could store the usersId liked by that profile in an array inside the documentId and then you can query to match the certain criterias and also that in the array does not exist that userId.