# Invalid Query. 'in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

The Query whereIn not works in firestore when the array has more than 10(size).

**Invalid Query. 'in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array.**

this is my code

```
  Query query = postRef.whereIn("id", postIdList).orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
                .setPageSize(3)
                .build();

        FirestorePagingOptions<Posts> options =  new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Posts>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(query,config,Posts.class)
                .build();


        firestorePagingAdapter = new FirestorePagingAdapter<Posts, PostPagingAdapter>(options) {


            @NonNull
            @Override
            public PostPagingAdapter onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.post_items,parent,false);
                return new PostPagingAdapter(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostPagingAdapter holder, int position, @NonNull Posts model) {
                holder.bind(model);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(@NonNull Exception e) {
                super.onError(e);
                Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
                super.onLoadingStateChanged(state);

                switch (state) {
                    case LOADING_INITIAL:
                    case LOADING_MORE:
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                        break;

                    case LOADED:

                    case FINISHED:
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;

                    case ERROR:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Slow internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        break;
                }

            }
        };


        bookmarks_recycler_view.setAdapter(firestorePagingAdapter);
```

Anybody pls help to get more than 10 arrayFields in Firestore WhereIn query

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you can pass no more than 10 values to `whereIn`. If you need more than 10 values, you'll need to execute multiple queries and merge the results in your application code.

Comment: We're not a code writing service here. If you're having trouble executing two queries and merging the results, edit your question to show what you tried.

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50132229/8303912) answer to see how to merge to queries, it is important to note `whenAllSuccess()` so that all queries are fetched before attempting to merge.