# How to get data from Firestore based on the person who is assigned to with many different ZIP Codes?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Following is the code I use to pull the data out from the `firestore`. However, as part of the development of the app, my requirement is also changed. Now, what I need is to pull the orders only for the person who is assigned to serve a particular area which can be identified with the ZIP Code which every order will have.
Presently, with my code, I can get the orders based on the status of the order and by the owner of the product who posted it, which is identified with the currently logged-in user. As per my new requirement, every ZIP Code is assigned to someone (a person can be assigned to provide service to many ZIP Codes.) and I need to show users only those orders that he is assigned to provide service at.
I know how to pull the data if only one ZIP is assigned to a service provider. But in this case, I have no idea how to design my database to assign ZIP codes to the service providers and to get the data.

I thought of doing it using `.whereIn` like I did for the 'order Status', but there are two issues, one, that there can't be two `.whereIn`s and, two, I do not want to hard code it. So I do not know how to do it, even if my thought was right.

I hope my question is clear.

```
        fun getOrderStatusList(fragment: OrdersByStatusFragment) {
        mFireStore.collection("orders")
            .whereIn(
                "order_status",
                listOf("Pending", "Order Received", "In Process", "Packed", "Shipped")
            )
            .whereEqualTo("product_owner_id", getCurrentUserID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val list: ArrayList<OrderStatus> = ArrayList()

                for (i in document.documents) {

                    val orderStatus = i.toObject(OrderStatus::class.java)!!
                    orderStatus.id = i.id

                    list.add(orderStatus)
                }

                fragment.successOrderStatusList(list)

            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                fragment.hideProgressDialog()
            }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Zip Codes that are assigned to each users are available as in the screenshot of the database. Document names are same as the id of the current user ID which is also available inside the document with the field name 'id'.

I want to get only those 'orders' that match any Zip code which is assigned to the user. Every order contain a field called zipCode.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's possible to change the database schema, I would think of something like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users
  |    |
  |    --- $uid
  |         |
  |         --- zipCodes: ["zipCodeOne", "zipCodeTwo"]
  |
  --- orders
       |
       --- $orderId
              |
              --- zipCode: "zipCodeOne"
              |
              --- status: "Pending"
```

Since a user can provide service to more than one ZIP code, I would add an array of zip codes to each and every user. To get the orders that correspond to a user, I would perform a query for each zip code a user has:

```
rootRef.collection("orders")
                    .whereEqualTo("zipCode", "zipCodeOne").get()

rootRef.collection("orders")
                    .whereEqualTo("zipCode", "zipCodeTwo").get()
```

Each statement from above will return a Task object, so you can pass all Task objects you have to the `whenAllSuccess` method, like explained my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore - Merging two queries locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally/50132229)

Once I got the order, I can filter them on the client according to the status. However, if you need to get all the orders a user has, according to a specific status, you can also add another whereEqualTo() call like this:

```
rootRef.collection("orders")
                    .whereEqualTo("zipCode", "zipCodeOne")
                    .whereEqualTo("status", "Pending")
                    .get()

rootRef.collection("orders")
                    .whereEqualTo("zipCode", "zipCodeTwo")
                    .whereEqualTo("status", "Pending")
                    .get()
```

Comment: Can you check my question after 'Edit' as I have updated it with new code.

Comment: Adding zip codes to a collection might incur multiple document reads. In my solution, there will always be a single document read, as you read only the User object for getting the zip codes. Besides that, most likely you aren't getting any results because I think you forgot to create an [index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305328/firestore-whereequalto-orderby-and-limit1-not-working).

Comment: OK. I am not an expert in coding. I am just learning, so my questions might sound silly. I have changed the structure of my database as you said. In your code, you have used multiple `.whereEqualTo` for Zip Codes, How can that help in my case as I cannot hard code the zip code as this will keep change and there is no fixed number of zip codes for everyone. Some people serve at 3 Zips but others may serve at 7 Zipcode. Can you help me

Comment: That's the reason why I have haded that array of zip codes in the User object. You should iterate that array and get all zip codes. Once you have the zip codes add each one of them to a whereEqualTo() call. You can chain whereEqualTo() method calls as many as you want. Is it ok now?

Comment: My doubt is, we do not know how many zip codes are there for each user then how can we decide many `.whereEqualTo` should be there in the code. Why can't we use `.whereIn`  instead?

Comment: There is no problem at all with the number of .whereEqualTo calls. You cannot use .whereIn because it can be used only once with a limited number of zip codes, which is 10. Is it ok now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234195/discussion-between-codist-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: Please add as a comment.

Comment: Now I know why I cannot use .wehreIn. But, I still don't know how to write the code. How many times I should write .whereEqualTo in the code, and how to iterate and get the Zip Code. Is it possible for you to provide the code. I have tried a lot. But failed.

Comment: *ow many times I should write .whereEqualTo*, you call ` .whereEqualTo` as many times as you want. *Is it possible for you to provide the code.*, You should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up. *I have tried a lot. But failed.*, No worries, add a question here, on Stackoverflow, so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Sure, I will mark it as answered once it's answered. Unfortunately, I couldn't get what I wanted. My issue is not solved yet. As I said, I can change the database schema as you suggested. But I do not know how to add zip codes to Firestore as you said. I added the zip codes like "785412", "963258", "123456" from the Firestore console with the field name "zip_code" just to check if this will work, but I do not know how to read these values one by one. Could you let me know the code that I can use for both adding the zip codes as you suggested and read them?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot with what have you tried so far. Regarding writing code, you should make your own attempt given the information in the answer and ask another question if something else comes up.

Comment: Here the main confusion, or perhaps what I do not know, is how to add the ZIP codes as an array. Because the number of zip codes will vary from user to user and what would be the field name in the Firestore. I am totally stuck due to this.

Comment: Create a POJO class, create a field of type `List<String>`. The list will be added in a Firestore document as an array. Having that array, you can then simply [update the elements that exist within that in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), right?

Comment: The reason I am not accepting your response as 'Answer' because I have not achieved what I wanted. However, all your comments that I found useful has been marked as 'useful'. I know you are an expert and I could accomplish what I want but you are providing only a bit of information which is not enough for a beginner like me. That's is the reason there have been many comments and yet I couldn't get what I wanted. I am trying my best with these pieces of information but I do not get anywhere with it. Anyway, I will try your last comment. Thanks.

Comment: I have asked another question that I have been struggling with for a few days. Could you please take a look at that? Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68235402/13935956

Comment: Finally, I have the ZIP Codes as you suggested. Could you now help me with this question?

Comment: Good to hear that made it work. Regarding the service question, I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write it to you.

Comment: Knowing that it worked, I will ask you more to accept my answer by clicking the checkmark under the left arrows. It should change the color in green. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I made any confusion here. You suggested I change the structure of my database in your very first comment. I was having trouble doing that and finally, I did it. Accordingly, I changed it and added a screenshot of it. My original question (this thread) is still not answered. Could you now look at the question where I have added the screenshot of the database and help me accomplish my task? As for accepting as the answer, I will definitely do that. Thank you.

Comment: I have provided you a solution. If you have hard times implementing it, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: If I ask a new question then that will be a duplicate question. Because the question in this thread is what I need an answer/solution for and I have not received any solution to that. In your response, you said if my database schema is changed... So I was trying to do that and that's where I had a hard time. Now that I have changed the structure of my database, could you now help me with this question?

Comment: I've asked another question which is also a part of this task. If I get an answer to that, hopefully, I could either complete my task or get close to completion. If I could accomplish my task then I can accept as the answer for both questions. I know I am getting close. Can you take a look at that? Thank you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/68235402/13935956

Comment: Ok, I just answered your second [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68235402/how-to-retrieve-data-from-firestore-that-stored-as-an-array-and-set-them-as-edit/68253986#68253986).

Comment: You said, *If I could accomplish my task then I can accept as the answer for both questions*. So I hope you consider accepting this answer as well. I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, Sir. I said I will accept it as the answer once I accomplish my task which is not yet done. I marked your response on the other post as the 'accepted answer'. But no offence, I am accepting it as the answer even though my task is incomplete. But, I still hope you will help me accomplish my task. Let me try myself and I will get back with the latest update on the task, I'll post a new question if required. But earlier a similar post of mine was marked as 'duplicate' and linked back to it. Anyway, you have been a great help. By the way, the delay in response was not deliberated. Thank you.

Comment: *I'll post a new question if required.* If you are moving forward and you have hard times implementing some functionalities, please post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: You're very welcome and glad I could help.

Comment: I am not able to post questions, getting a message - "Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more."

Comment: Hmm, I never received such a message. If you think it's some kind of bug or error, you should consider writing to the StackOverflow team.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work the way you said (I think I got you right). Using multiple `.whereEqualTo`,  as explained in your answer, didn't help me get what I need. I posted the question and I am still not able to get the order that matches any of the Zip Codes in the ZipList when there are more than 10 items in the ZipList. Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68275650/13935956

Comment: As I see, you already got an answer, which I can say it's perfect for what you need, but only if you have at most 10 elements. However, I have also edited my answer. So please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use multiple array queries, you should consider aggregating field values or separating the field types to boolean flags. such as `FieldName:true` pairs.

```
.whereEqualTo("Order_Recieved", "true")`
```

You could store the ZIP code in an array, while silly, this allows you to do an array contains-any

```
val citiesRef = db.collection("cities")

citiesRef.whereEqualTo("pending", "true")
.whereEqualTo("orderRecieved", "true")
.whereEqualTo("inProgress", "true")
.whereEqualTo("isPacked", "true")
.whereEqualTo("shipped", "true")
Order Received.whereArrayContainsAny("postcode", listOf("05723", "36236"))
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any

Comment: I am using '.whereIn' to filter the status and there can't be more than one .whereIn in query.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question that I cannot hardcode Zip Cpdes, I used another way. I have updated it in my question. Please read after 'Edit'. Thanks.

Comment: the zip codes can be dynamically populated if you have a source for it, passing them as a value would suffice - if the relationship is more direct to the user, you can assign the user.uid as a field value as well. Alternatively, if it is multi-relational, a team or area UID would suffice for a zip code if needed. I think you are on the right track

Comment: Can you check Edit 2 in my question? Thanks.