# How to get data from Firebase that match two criteria where one criteria is an array?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the following code to get an array of data from `Firestore`, an array of Zip Codes (retrieved from the collection called 'users'). I then want to get data from another collection (called 'orders') that match with any of the Zip Codes in the array as well as the 'order status' that matches Pending, Packed, Processing.

```
        fun getZipCodesFromFirebase(fragment: OrdersByStatusFragment) {

    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    val rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val followingRef = rootRef.collection("users")
    val uidRef = followingRef.document(uid)
    uidRef.get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            val document = task.result
            if (document.exists()) {
                val zipCodes = document.toObject(User::class.java)?.zip_codes
                Log.d("Zip Codes", zipCodes.toString())
                
                getOrderStatusList(fragment, zipCodes)

            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "No such document")
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "get failed with ", task.exception)
        }
    }

}
```

I then tried the following code to get the orders with mentioned order statuses and orders that match with any of the Zip Codes. But I couldn't get it correctly.

```
    fun getOrderStatusList(fragment: OrdersByStatusFragment, zipList: List<String>?) {

    mFireStore.collection("orders")
        .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(0))
        .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(1))
        .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(2))
        .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(3))
        .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(4))
        .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(5))
        .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(6))
        .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(7))
        .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(8))
        .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(9))
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            val list: ArrayList<OrderStatus> = ArrayList()

            for (i in document.documents) {

                val orderStatus = i.toObject(OrderStatus::class.java)!!
                orderStatus.id = i.id

                if (orderStatus.order_status == "Pending" || orderStatus.order_status == "Packed" || orderStatus.order_status == "In Process"
                    || orderStatus.order_status == "Order Received") {
                    list.add(orderStatus)
                }

            }
            Log.d("Zip Code", list.toString())
            fragment.successOrderStatusList(list)

        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            fragment.hideProgressDialog()
        }
}
```

In short, I want orders that match Zip Codes and order status. Where Zip code**s** are retrieved from another collection called `users` in an array, and order status that is hard-coded.

The database structure can be seen in the following screenshot.

Collection 'user' with the field 'zip_codes'.

[image]

Collection 'order' that contain fields 'order_status' and 'zip_codes'

[image]

I hope my question is clear enough.

Thank you.

**Edit: >> Latest working code.**

```
    fun getOrderStatusList(fragment: OrdersByStatusFragment, zipList: List<String>?) {

    mFireStore.collection("orders")
        .whereIn("address.zipCode", zipList!!)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            val list: ArrayList<OrderStatus> = ArrayList()

            for (i in document.documents) {

                val orderStatus = i.toObject(OrderStatus::class.java)!!
                orderStatus.id = i.id

                if (orderStatus.order_status == "Pending" || orderStatus.order_status == "Packed" || orderStatus.order_status == "In Process"
                    || orderStatus.order_status == "Order Received"
                ) {
                    list.add(orderStatus)
                }

            }
            Log.d("Zip Code", list.toString())
            fragment.successOrderStatusList(list)

        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            fragment.hideProgressDialog()
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This construct:

```
mFireStore.collection("orders")
    .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(0))
    .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(1))
    .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(2))
    .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(3))
    .whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(4))
```

Filters the results to contain only elements where the `zipCode` property of the top-level `address` field is equal to `zipList?.get(0)`, **and** equal to `zipList?.get(1)`, **and** equal to `zipList?.get(2)`, etc. Since no single field can be equal to multiple values, this returns nothing.

More likely you're looking for an [`array-contains-any` condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any), which would look like this:

```
citiesRef.whereArrayContainsAny("zipCode", zipList!)
```

Similarly to filter on `order_status`, you can use a `in` condition from the same documentation:

```
citiesRef
  .whereIn("order_status", listOf("Pending", "Packed", "In Process"))
```

Unfortunately, you can't combine these two conditions, as the documentation says:

> You can use at most one `in`, `not-in`, or `array-contains-any` clause per query. You can't combine these operators in the same query.

So you'll have to do one of the conditions in the query, and then filter the other in your application code.

Comment: I tried `mFireStore.collection("orders")
            .whereArrayContainsAny("address.zipCode",zipList!!)` and it returned nothing. When I used `mFireStore.collection("orders")
.whereEqualTo("address.zipCode", zipList?.get(0))` I get the result as expected. But I can check for value from one position. `zipList?.get(0))`. If I add value from next position in the array, it returns nothing as you explained in your response. Isn't `.whereArrayContainsAny` supposed to work?

Comment: Your second screenshot looks very different from the first one. To find the documents where that zip code matches one of the value in the list, should be: `.whereIn("address.zipCode", zipList!!)`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I have updated my latest code in the question. Could you take a look at that and tell me if that's OK or need any improvements? I filter out by the 'order status' using an `if` statement.

 I have a doubt that if this will still work if `zipList` contains more than 10 items.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear that the limit on the number of items is 10. After that you will have to fire a separate query for each 10 items, or find another way to perform the query.  If neither of those is acceptable for you, consider whether Firestore is the right database for you/your project.