# Firestore OR queries using Java

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to perform OR query operation in Firestore using Java client. I am trying to merge the queries.

Code :

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query firstQuery = rootRef...
Query secondQuery = rootRef...

Task firstTask = firstQuery.get();
Task secondTask = secondQuery.get();

Task combinedTask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(firstTask, secondTask).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
         //Do what you need to do with your list
    }
});
```

as suggested in [Firestore - Merging two queries locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally)

But it is not working for me, could anyone please suggest to me how to join query shot operations using java client for fire store.

Comment: Is your onSuccess even triggered?

Comment: I am unable to create the task object, For me :query.get() does not gives back task object , ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot>  qs = query.get();  object is of this type , I am using maven dependency dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
   <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
   <version>8.0.1</version>
  </dependency><dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
   <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
   <version>1.23.0</version>
  </dependency> in  java project

Comment: So you aren't using Java for an Android application?

Comment: I am using java , but it is not an android application

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Java for Android, then you should consider using [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/#java_2). In the linked documentation you'll find all the necessary details that can help you interact with Firebase.

> Access Google Cloud resources like Cloud Storage buckets and Cloud Firestore databases associated with your Firebase projects.

And yes, the get() method that is called on a Query object doesn't return a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) object, but a [ApiFuture](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/1.7.0/apidocs/com/google/api/core/ApiFuture.html).

As far as I can see, there is no method there that can help you combine two queries. You can only [addListener()](https://googleapis.github.io/api-common-java/1.7.0/apidocs/com/google/api/core/ApiFuture.html#addListener-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) and read the data accordingly.

However, the is a workaround that can help you achieve that, which is by using a CompletableFuture. I personally didn't use it in development, as I'm working mainly with Android, but you can check this out:

- https://theboreddev.com/combining-multiple-api-calls-with-completablefuture/

> I want to perform OR query operation in Firestore using Java.

When it comes to Firestore, you might also take into consideration using the [in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) operator to combine up to 10 equality (==) clauses on the same field with a logical OR.