# How to compare EditText value with array value stored in firestore?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

```
addaddress.setOnClickListener {
            val pincoder = zipcode.text.toString().trim()
            val pinCodeList = listOf("201014", "201301")
            val productsRef =  FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Pincode")
                .document("zipcollect").collection("zipcodes")
            productsRef.whereArrayContainsAny("pin_code", pinCodeList).get().addOnCompleteListener {
                if (pincoder.equals(it.isSuccessful.toString()) == 0)
                {
                    for (document in it.result!!) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.id + " => " + document.data)
                        Toast.makeText(this,"We Deliver Here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"We Don't Deliver Here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
```

[firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOScf.png)

Here's a screenshot of data stored in firestore

Comment: whereArrayContainsAny can be perform on collection and return list of documents and you are tring to get field

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell Firestore, hey Firestore return me all documents where the `pin_code` array contains all elements of `pinCodeList`.

To solve this, you might consider using a Map rather than an array. Your document should look like this:"

```
pin_codes
   |
   --- code_one: 201014
   |
   --- code_two: 303007
   |
   --- code_three: 201301
```

And then perform a separate [in query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) for each code, that looks like this:

```
val firstCodeQuery = productsRef.whereIn("pin_codes.code_one", Arrays.asList("201014", "201301"))
val firstTask = firstCodeQuery.get()
```

Do the same for the second and the third query. If one of the values in the List doesn't exist in the Map, doesn't exist in Map, then simply stop querying. If all are present, simply collect the results on the client using my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore - Merging two queries locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally/50132229)

Alternatively, you can perform a [whereArrayContains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) operation for each element in the list.

Comment: You're very welcome, crazydose.

Comment: It would be wonderful if you can help me with one more question sir. This is the question, How to clear cart list after placing an order in android using Kotlin?

Comment: Without seeing the code you are using, I cannot be much of a help. SO please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Answer (score 0):

**whereArrayContainsAny** can be perform on collection and return list of documents and you are tring to get field.

> array-contains-any
>
> Use the array-contains-any operator to combine up to 10 array-contains
> clauses on the same field with a logical OR. An array-contains-any
> query returns documents where the given field is an array that
> contains one or more of the comparison values:

You can read here for more detail about [array-contains-any](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any)
You can perform your action like this

```
val pincoder = zipcode.text.toString().trim()
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("Pincode")
    .document("zipcollect")
    .collection("zipcodes")
    .document("Am0U....<Fill your doc ref>").get()
    .addOnCompleteListener {
        it.let {
            if (it.isSuccessful && it.result != null) {
                val pinCodeList = it.result["pin_code"] as List<String>
                if(pinCodeList.contains(pincoder)){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"We Deliver Here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"We Don't Deliver Here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .addOnFailureListener {
        AppLog.e("===========", "Data fail " + it)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy, it's working now

Comment: You're very welcome, @crazydose.