# How to retrieve data from sub-collections with Firebase firestore to Viewpager in Java, Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a Java Android project. My goal is to make an application that gives the user information about countries. Whichever country the user chooses, the country and information about that country will be displayed by scrolling. I used Firestore and ViewPager for this.

[image]

[image]

MyAdapter.Java

```
public class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<Kart> kartList;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Kart> kartList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.kartList = kartList;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return kartList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        ((ViewPager)container).removeView((View) object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item,container,false);

        ImageView kart_image=view.findViewById(R.id.kart_image);
        TextView kart_title=view.findViewById(R.id.kart_title);
        TextView kart_description=view.findViewById(R.id.kart_description);

        //Set Data

        Picasso.get().load(kartList.get(position).getImage()).into(kart_image);
        kart_title.setText(kartList.get(position).getName());
        kart_description.setText(kartList.get(position).getDescription());

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Kartlar.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kartlar);

        kartlar= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("MyCards");

        loadKart();

    private void loadKart() {

        kartlar.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            List<Kart> kartList=new ArrayList<>();
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot kartSnapShot:snapshot.getChildren())
                    kartList.add(kartSnapShot.getValue(Kart.class));
                iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadSuccess(kartList);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                iFirebaseLoadDone.onFirebaseLoadFailed(error.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

Kart.Java

```
public class Kart {
    private String name, description, image;

    public Kart() {
    }

    public Kart(String name, String description, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

If all the information is under the same Collection, I can retrieve it from the ViewPager. But when I categorize the countries, I don't know how to get the data from the sub-collections and sub-documents. I want to retrieve data from sub-collection and sub-documents to ViewPager. What can I do for this?

Comment: You have to make separate queries for each subcollection. The nested documents will never show up in a query on the parent collection.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson How can I make seperate queries for each subcollection?

Comment: Review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) about [subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections).

Comment: @DougStevenson I looked at the link you shared, but I couldn't find a clear solution there.

Answer (score 1):

Queries in Firestore are shallow, they only get documents from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way you can get documents from a top-level collection and sub-collections in a single query. To solve your problem, you have to perform separate queries for each sub-collection you're interested in getting documents. So if you want, for example, to get the result of two queries and combine the results, then please check my solution from the following answer:

- [Firestore - Merging two queries locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118345/firestore-merging-two-queries-locally/50132229)

Comment: thak you for your reply.

Comment: Hey Burak. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: I want to say thank you. Your answer help me. Sorry for lating.

Comment: Good to hear that, Burak.